Unexpected behaviour in NestJS / NATS microservice
I have a NestJS app that uses NATS microservices (using NatsJetStreamTransport). In one microservice I have a controller (A) with following event listener:
@EventPattern("businessRule.apply")
async applyRule(
  @Payload() { ruleName, input }: { ruleName: string; input: any },
  @Ctx() context: NatsJetStreamContext,
): Promise<any> {
  const result = await this.businessRulesService.applyRule(ruleName, input);
  this.jetStreamClient.emit("businessRule.appliedResult", result);
  context.message.ack();
  return;
}

In another microservice I have a controller (B) with the following event listener:
@EventPattern("businessRule.appliedResult")
async appliedResult(
  @Payload() result: any,
  @Ctx() context: NatsJetStreamContext,
): Promise<any> {
  console.log("appliedResult", result);
  context.message.ack();
  return result;
}

When I emit an event from a third NestJS REST API service like so:
jetStreamClient.emit("businessRule.apply", {ruleName: 'r1', input: {ok: true}});

where jetStreamClient is NatsJetStreamClientProxy, the event is captured by controller A. But the event emitted by controller A (businessRule.appliedResult) is NOT captured by controller B. However, if I emit that same event from the API service, it is captured by controller B!
What am I missing here?

Resolved it. Issue was that the NatsJetStreamTransport was not configured properly in controller A's module.ts. So events emitted from it were not reaching the NATS server.
